# How to get max(0.10)+1 as 0.11 in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have values as 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 in a table. I have used below query to populate 0.0, 0.4, ...0.10 in to the table.

I am trying to add 4 more records in to the table and expecting the values to be 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14. But my query populated all of them as 0.10 therefore duplicates.

Below is my query and please help me to resolve this issue.

--Query

```
SELECT nvl(MAX(substr(sequence_number, instr(sequence_number, '.') + 1, 1)) + 1, '0') 
FROM TESTING_TBL;
```

---Sample table creation scripts

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT ALL INTO TESTING_TBL ( sequence_number ) VALUES ( '0.0' )
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.1')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.2')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.3')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.4')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.5')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.6')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.7')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.8')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.9')
    INTO  TESTING_TBL (SEQUENCE_NUMBER) VALUES ('0.10')
SELECT '1' FROM dual;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `VARCHAR2`? Shouldn't you be using something like `DECIMAL(10, 2)`?

Comment: Please use two independent INT column (storing integer values). Increase accordingly e.g. MAX(num1)+1. Use a *virtual column* to get the string presentation.

Comment: Don't use the strategy you are using, like MAX(...). Use a proper database SEQUENCE, or a database IDENTITY column for it. There are multiple race conditions you are not aware or, plus parallelism will defeat your MAX() stategy (it won't work).

Comment: My ultimate goal is to insert this generated number in to the Oracle base column, TASK_NUMBER (VARCHAR2) in PA.PA_TASKS table. So I have used same data_type is my staging table column. I have different numbering requirements on same column, a numbering type starts with 0.0 and increments by 0.1 (like 0.2, 0.3 etc). Another numbering type starts with 1.0, 2.0 etc. Similarly I have many numbering types. All scenarios where the number increments before the decimals are working fine. I am having issue with only the numbering types where I have to increment after the decimal...

Comment: issue with after the decimal records only after 10th record which is 0.10. Sorry if I am not clear and appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first split the string in two part, than convert both parts in numbers and apply the `MAX` and increase by 1.

This is a sample query

```
with tbl as (
select 
  SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
  to_number(substr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,1,instr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,'.')-1)) num1,
  to_number(substr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,instr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,'.')+1)) num2
from TESTING_TBL)
select SEQUENCE_NUMBER, NUM1, NUM2
from tbl
order by num1, num2;
```

giving data as

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER                      NUM1       NUM2
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
0.0                                     0          0
0.1                                     0          1
....
0.8                                     0          8
0.9                                     0          9
0.10                                    0         10
```

Now with numbers you may safe find the MAX and add 1

```
with tbl as (
select 
  SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
  to_number(substr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,1,instr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,'.')-1)) num1,
  to_number(substr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,instr(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,'.')+1)) num2
from TESTING_TBL)
select to_char(max(NUM1))||'.'||to_char(max(NUM2)+1) new_key
from tbl
```

which produce the expected result

```
NEW_KEY                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.11
```

Note that you should re-thing your desing if this is the optimal approach. As a better and safer option I'd consider storing two INT column (type safe!) and defining the text presentation only as a virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING_TBL2 (num1 int, num2 int);

alter table TESTING_TBL2 add  SEQUENCE_NUMBER AS (to_char(num1)||'.'||to_char(num2)) VIRTUAL  ;
```

add test data

```
INSERT ALL INTO TESTING_TBL2 ( num1, num2 ) VALUES ( 0,0 )
-- ....
    INTO  TESTING_TBL2 (num1, num2) VALUES ( 0,9 )
    INTO  TESTING_TBL2 (num1, num2) VALUES ( 0,10)
SELECT '1' FROM dual;
```

now this simple query provides the new keys

```
select max(num1) num1, max(num2)+1 num2 from TESTING_TBL2;
```

Complete data

```
select * from TESTING_TBL2;

      NUM1       NUM2 SEQUENCE_NUMBER                                                                  
---------- ---------- ------------------- 
         0          0 0.0                                                                              
         0          9 0.9                                                                              
         0         10 0.10
```

Remember also, that the `MAX + 1` algorithm for allocating new keys work best in an *single user* enviromnemt.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the various reasonable comments about whether this is even a good idea ...

The immediate problem is that you are limiting the length of the substring to 1:

SELECT nvl(MAX(substr(sequence_number, instr(sequence_number, '.') + 1 **, 1**)) + 1, '0')

When there is only 1 digit after the decimal, this works fine, so you get as far as inserting 0.10.  At that point, the substr returns "1", not "10" as you presumably want. My guess is this results in you attempting to insert "0.2" again, causing a uniqueness violation.

If it works for all your inputs, you should just remove that length parameter.  But if you have to handle more complicated strings like say '0.10.3', you may need to use regexes to do the parsing.  Or, as suggested by others, store the subcomponents of this string as separate numeric value and concatenate them using a virtual column or during insert into a final table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking your time on my issue. Appreciate all your efforts.

I separated before and after decimal numbers and used below query to increment the after decimal number. It resolved my issue.

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(SUBSTR(sequence_number, 3)+1),'0')
FROM TESTING_TBL;
```